# Clean Architecture Vs MVPC/MVC/MVP

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns, model-view-controller, clean-architecture

I'm studing [Uncle Bob Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), and trying to get comparasion in many differents aspects about witch design pattern should I use for my IOS/Android Projects.

Ok, I noticed that clean arch is very powerfull and rouboust, but at the same time, in my opinion, is it too much overhead with the number of class and files that I should create.

So my question is, is this design patter more advantageous than use MVC/MVP/MVPC?? Isn't it too much overhead?? Which architecture is it the best for IOS/Android Projects?

I didn't find any good reason yet that justify I change from others design patters to Clean arch, except the fact that UI is totaly isolated from main code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adopting a 'Clean' architecture, along with Hexagonal/Ports & Adapters/Onion/Lifesaver/Screaming, does not exclude the use of separated presentation patterns such as MVC.

The original intent of such an approach is to:

> Allow an application to equally be driven by users, programs, automated test or batch scripts, and to be developed and tested in isolation from its eventual run-time devices and databases ([Cockburn](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture), 2005).

If you think your application will benefit from such an approach then I would argue that it's a good approach to follow.

BTW, IMHO, there is no 'best architecture'.

Comment: Well said for: "there is no 'best architecture'"